# Integral of $\sin(x)\exp(-a/\sin x)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I'm looking for a way of evaluating $$\int_0^\pi\sin x \exp(-a/\sin x)dx$$ to get a second order Bickley function $K_2(a)$, which is basically the same  integral, but $\cos x$ instead of $\sin x$ and the limits change from $0$ to $\pi/2$, which is understandable.

I'm a bit lost what kind of variable substitution could I do. Any suggestions? 
I have tried $-a/\sin x = u$, but that doesnt seem to give reasonable results. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Ashkhen has shown some effort.

Comment: What are the integration limits?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that;  from 0 to π

Comment: The function's symmetric over $x=\pi/2$ so you could do 2$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\left(x\right)\exp\left(\frac{-a}{\sin x}\right)dx$. This might be easier since the integrand is monotonic over $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: The integral is equal to $$f(a)=2\int_1^\infty e^{-a u} \frac{du}{u^2 \sqrt{u^2-1}}$$ Also $$f''(a)= 2 K_0(a)$$ where $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of a second kind

Comment: Just a thought (probably not relevant) but if $f(a)$ is the value of the integral as a function of $a$, $f(a)\approx 1.91 e^{1.22a}$ for $0<a<8$. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL4Aq.png), [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tx7cscchx4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment.

Though I now consider the limits to be from $0$ to $\pi/2$, so the final function would have to be multiplied by $2$.

Substitution: $$u=\frac{1}{\sin x}$$

makes the integral:

$$f(a)=\int_1^\infty e^{-a u} \frac{du}{u^2 \sqrt{u^2-1}}=\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\cosh^2 t}e^{-a \cosh t}$$

This makes it obvious that:

$$f''(a)=K_0(a)$$

Where the initial conditions can be easily found from the original integral:

$$f(0)=1 \\ f'(0)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Does $f(a)$ have a closed form? Probably not a nice one. We can always use numerical methods.

Comment: As you showed above, the integral results in modified bessel function of second order, which can be approximated by Bickley inetgral, and that can be further numerically solved in Matlab, for example. Thanks a lot, btw.

Comment: PS In case you're interested; http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-143/S0025-5718-1978-0471262-6/S0025-5718-1978-0471262-6.pdf

Comment: @AshkhenNalbandian, I have never heard of Bickley functions before now, but as they are defined by the integrals like that one, I don't really understand what do you want to do? Numerically evaluate the integral? Find some other closed form? Please clarify the question if there's something in particular you'd like to know

Comment: At this point my questions is fully answered. I have to solve the Bickley function (mostly used in neutron transport theory, in reactor physics), but I just wanted to fill the gap (since it is not done in literature) of obtaining the Bickley function from the integral I posted.

Comment: @AshkhenNalbandian, but the paper you just linked to me explicitly defines the functions and does the same substitutions I did, so basically my answer should be of no use to you. It would make sense to link this paper in your original post and then clarify what do you want to do (I think probably numerically evaluate these functions, which the paper is concerned with)

Comment: the paper defines Bickley functions and discusses their features, but I do not see the derivation I needed. Maybe it is better to rephrase my initial question: I wanted to show that the integral I posted results in modified bessel function, and as such could be expressed in terms of the Bickley function.

Comment: the first integral is just a combinations of struves and bessels, but the remaining one seems to be impossible

Comment: @tired, yes, I noticed the same thing. Wolfram gives a solution in terms of hypergeometric and meijer functions, but it's not that useful

Comment: In fact the result is $\text{Ki}_2(a)$ according to http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_483.htm